# Language fallback version not indexing

Tags: coveo, language-fallback

I am struggling with an issue that I can't get my head around of. I have a Sitecore 9.3 solution, for which I installed the Coveo for Sitecore module. The solution is multilingual, 3 languages (Netherlands, Belgium, German), from which the Belgium one was set to have the Netherlands as fallback.

Now, in order to have an extra field in the index, I created an `IComputedIndexField` (*Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields*). Checked the component in debug when indexing is triggered, works just fine for the Netherlands and German, but for Belgium, it is not triggered. The site works just fine for years now, having the language fallback set.

Does anyone have any ideas what might go wrong here or what I need to change?

Comment: Did you add below 2 settings you can find in the index element configuration?
 <index id="Coveo_master_index" ...>
  <enableItemLanguageFallback>false</enableItemLanguageFallback>
  <enableFieldLanguageFallback>false</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
</index>

Comment: I see those settings in the Coveo.SearchProvider.config that I have. But shouldn't these 2 settings be set to *true* for that to have any effect?

Comment: Yeah these should be set to true, also follow this - https://answers.coveo.com/questions/16442/get-fall-back-language-item-when-language-specific.html

Comment: Yeah, If I set those to *true* works. Jesus. Very stupid of me not to check the config file for the coveo search provider. I saw that the Sitecore ones were set to true, but did not go deeper into the Coveo configs. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am adding this as a answer, please accept those then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below 2 settings you can find in the index element configuration -

```
<index id="Coveo_master_index" ...>
  <enableItemLanguageFallback>true</enableItemLanguageFallback>
  <enableFieldLanguageFallback>true</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
</index>
```

This setting will enable language fallback for you.